# Using a Moose alias with MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors

Tags: perl, oop, constructor, moose

I'm trying to use an alias with [MooseX::Aliases](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aAliases) and [MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aConstructor%3a%3aAllErrors)

However, the two don't seem to play nicely together. Consider the following example:

```
package Alias
{
  use Moose;
  use MooseX::Aliases;
  use MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors;

  has foo => (
    is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1, alias => 'bar'
  );
}

use strict;
use warnings;
use Alias;

my $obj;

eval {
  $obj = Alias->new( bar => 'alias_value' );
};

if ($@)
{
  foreach my $error ( $@->errors )
  {
    print $error ."\n";
    print $error->message ."\n";
  }

  exit 1;
}

print $obj->bar ."\n";
$obj->foo( 'new_alias_value' );
print $obj->foo."\n";

1;
```

This should allow me to create an Alias object using the 'bar' alias... shouldn't it? Does anyone know if `MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors` is supposed to support aliased attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, in that it violates expectations, but it's not easily resolvable -- the problem is that MooseX::Aliases modifies what arguments are allowed/accepted in the constructor, but MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors is not aware of this, so when it looks at the passed values at construction time, it errors out when there is no 'agency' field.

This gets around the situation by manually moving the aliased field before MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors sees it:

```
around BUILDARGS => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    my %args = @_;

    $args{agency} //= delete $args{company};

    $self->$orig(%args);
};
```

The good news is that this has hope of working better in the future, because
there are plans for MooseX::Aliases to be cored, which would force all other
extensions (e.g. MXCAE) to support the alias feature properly.

Comment: Thanks again Ether. I just gave this a try and it works how one would expect it to now. But it is more of a workaround than a solution... Is there any scope for this to be made the default behaviour of MXCAE in a future version?